# Laravel mix & react - Module build failed on inline import

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

I seem to be having an issue when building my frontend using Laravel mix.

I'm using [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) for loading components with promises, as for routing I make use of a declarative config file:

```
export default [
    {
        path: '/clients',
        exact: true,
        auth: true,
        component: Loadable({
            loader: () => import('./screens/index'),
            loading: LoadingComponent,
        }),
    },
]
```

When building the js files, I get following error (pointing to the 'i' of import):

> ERROR in ./resources/js/modules/clients/routes.js Module build failed:
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token (10:26)

When searching the web I came across the fact that, when you wanted to use arrow functions or class properties, you'd need to add a Babel plugin (babel-plugin-transform-class-properties).

So I did add a .babelrc file with following config (it also seems that laravel-mix would automatically make use of the babelrc file):

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Still no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2016"],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hey, it seems all specific packages of babel's presets are deprecated (see: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-es2016). So I installed **@babel/preset-env** but then I get the following error: 

Error: Couldn't find preset "es2016" relative to directory